# How to use FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) in Cordova Angular 4 application

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am creating a hybrid app using Angular 4 and Cordova as I want to target both desktop and mobile platforms with single code base. I have followed following directory structure of my project:

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL8vs.png)

I am developing the application in angular 4 and use to build using Angular CLI. I have hook which copy the angular build into cordova 'www' folder and then I create the apk. 
Issue is I want to use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) in my cordova app to receive messages from server but I can't as I am developing in Angular 4 (Ref. directory structure above). Could anyone help how I can use cordova plugins with angular 4.
I am open to change the directory structure if required.

Comment: Hi Gaurav. Welcome to SO! If possible it's much better to include the information from the other side of the link on our site instead of theirs to help with futureproofing. There is always the possibility that the website you linked to could be removed which would then make your question useless to other people who have you problem. Can you please consider amending this?

Comment: @EthanField I have updated the same. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you include the picture instead of a link to the picture it requires even less effort for someone reading the question and there's no reason not to.

Comment: @EthanField I want to put the image but SO! restricted me to do so as I am a new user.

Comment: Regardless, I've added the picture back as a suggested edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. 
1. Just need to add the FCM plugin in cordova project by running 
   following command:
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
2. Now in angular project do the following changes in "app.component.ts" file:

```
ngOnInit() {
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

onDeviceReady() {
FCMPlugin.getToken((token) => {
        this.pushtoken = token;
        console.log('getToken:', token);
        if (!token) {
            setTimeout(this.getToken, 1000);
        }
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
    });
}
```